# Никогда не выполняется блок else

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Сегодня столкнулся со странным: При отладке некорректно работающей программы, обнаружил, что в этом куске кода:

```
begin
  Self.MRead[ci-1][cj-1].TypeMatrix := Self.DCell.TypeMatrix;
  // Тот самый if
  if ((Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = I) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = R) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = B)) then
    if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = 0)) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then
      Self[ci,cj] := Value
  else //Никогда не выполняется
    if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = '')) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then
      Self[ci,cj] := Value;
end //; отсутствует, потому что блок внутри if, перед else
```

Программа игнорирует оператор `else`: Если условие `if` выполнено - идёт в `then`, иначе просто переходит к выполнению следующей инструкции (следующей интерации цикла). Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно отформатированный код - это, конечно, хорошо, однако Паскаль при определении вложенности операторов ориентируется только на ключевые слова: Если вы пишете оператор `else`, он считается относящемся к ближайшему ранее встреченному оператору `if`, если вы **явно** не указали обратное с помощью операторов `begin` и `end`. Приведённый код компилятор понимает так:

```
begin
  Self.MRead[ci-1][cj-1].TypeMatrix := Self.DCell.TypeMatrix;
  // Тот самый if
  if ((Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = I) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = R) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = B)) then
    begin
      // Ближайший к else if
      if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = 0)) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then 
        begin
          Self[ci,cj] := Value
        end
      else begin
        if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = '')) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then
          begin
            Self[ci,cj] := Value;
          end;
      end;
    end;
end
```

Как видно из этого кода, если "тот самый" `if` вернёт ложь, то программа действительно закончит на нём проверку, так как считает, что инструкция `else` для данного случая не определена.

Чтобы избежать неверной интерпретации вашего кода со стороны компилятора, следует явно указать, что оператор `else` находится в вышестоящем блоке программы, по отношению ко второму (вложенному) оператору `if`:

```
begin
  Self.MRead[ci-1][cj-1].TypeMatrix := Self.DCell.TypeMatrix;
  if ((Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = I) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = R) or (Self.DCell.TypeMatrix = B)) then
    begin //Вложенный блок программы
      if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = 0)) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then
        Self[ci,cj] := Value
    end //Конец вложенного блока
  else //Теперь, ближайший if в том же блоке программы - тот самый,
      //инструкция будет выполнена.
    if ((Self[ci,cj] = OldDefValue) or (Self[ci,cj] = '')) and (Self[ci,cj]<>Value) then
      Self[ci,cj] := Value;
end
```